# Sencha Cmd is not generating ExtJS app

Tags: javascript, extjs, build-process, sencha-cmd

Hi I am trying to learn and getting started with ExtJS ([from here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/cmd/cmd_app.html)). but seems either I am missing something, or bugged by some issue here. Whenever I am trying to execute first basic simple command:  `sencha generate app -ext Myapp ./app` its failed with below exceptions:

```
Sencha Cmd v5.0.0.160
[ERR] java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(DatatypeConverter.java:547)
 at com.sencha.util.StringUtil.toBase64(StringUtil.java:202)
 at com.sencha.tools.generator.DataStoreImpl.get(DataStoreImpl.java:103)
 at com.sencha.tools.generator.Generator$1.doMerge(Generator.java:464)
 at com.sencha.tools.generator.Generator$Mode$3.dispatch(Generator.java:269)
 at com.sencha.tools.generator.Generator.generateFileToFile(Generator.java:449)
 at com.sencha.tools.generator.Generator.generateFileToDir(Generator.java:441)
 at com.sencha.tools.generator.Generator.generateDirToDir(Generator.java:434)
 at com.sencha.tools.generator.Generator.generateDirToDir(Generator.java:429)
 at com.sencha.tools.generator.Generator.generate(Generator.java:148)
 at com.sencha.tools.pkg.LocalRepository.init(LocalRepository.java:130)
 at com.sencha.tools.pkg.LocalRepository.init(LocalRepository.java:184)
 at com.sencha.command.environment.WorkspaceRepository.getLocalRepository(WorkspaceRepository.java:274)
 at com.sencha.command.environment.FrameworkEnvironment.loadFrameworkPackage(FrameworkEnvironment.java:180)
 at com.sencha.command.generator.GeneratorCommands$WorkspaceCommand.getParameters(GeneratorCommands.java:146)
 at com.sencha.command.BasePluginCommands$BasePluginCommand.doExecute(BasePluginCommands.java:26)
 at com.sencha.command.generator.GeneratorCommands$WorkspaceCommand.execute(GeneratorCommands.java:116)
 at com.sencha.command.generator.GeneratorCommands$AppCommand.generateWorkspace(GeneratorCommands.java:468)
 at com.sencha.command.generator.GeneratorCommands$AppCommand.execute(GeneratorCommands.java:313)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at com.sencha.util.MethodInvoker$Arguments.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:175)
 at com.sencha.cli.Command.dispatch(Command.java:43)
 at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:64)
 at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:64)
 at com.sencha.command.Sencha.dispatch(Sencha.java:71)
 at com.sencha.command.Sencha.main(Sencha.java:139)
```

When I am trying to execute `sencha generate app MyApp ./app` is throws below exception:

```
Sencha Cmd v5.0.0.160 
[ERR] Unable to locate 'framework.dir' property from sencha.cfg and no framework directory specified
[ERR] Please ensure this command was executed from a valid framework directory
[ERR] No Framework specified
```

What is framework.dir here ? **I have downloaded Sencha ExtJS v5.0.0 as well**, do I need to keep it somewhere ?

**Update**
After running `sencha -sdk /path/to/extjs-5.0.0 generate app MyApp ./app` giving same result, saying repo is not initialized properly.

I have installed both Ruby v1.9.3 and Sencha Cmd v5.0.0.160 which you can see on top of exception above. any idea how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1):

You must either run `Sencha Cmd` from the directory where you installed ext or you must give it path to where Ext is installed.

This should work:

```
sencha -sdk /path/to/ext/ generate app MyApp /where/you/want/the/app
```

Comment: Something very weird, I had no choice than hard reset/format my desktop machine !! :( **after that everything working smoothly..!!** if any one knows the exact root cause, please share it.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid any confusion just pass full path of "sencha cmd", "sencha sdk" and your desired application target directory.

Like

```
/Users/vishnu/bin/Sencha/Cmd/5.1.0.26/sencha -sdk /Users/vishnu/Documents/senchaworkspace/ext-5.0.1 generate app TutorialApp /Users/vishnu/Documents/senchaworkspace/TutorialApp
```

This works for me perfectly

Comment: Yes You are right. There was some weird issue with my machine, I had to hard reset it in order to get it worked properly.